# Browser has duplicate cookies variable

Tags: php, setcookie

My cookies has 2 values for the same variable:

```
slng=zh; HstCfa1189204=1435218026929; HstCmu1189204=1435218026929; HstCla1189204=1437300574160; 
HstPn1189204=11; HstPt1189204=26; HstCnv1189204=8; HstCns1189204=12;
last_position=styles%2F; slng=vi
```

`slng` variable has 2 values. 
I'm using php `setcookie` with syntax `setcookie('slng', "vi", 0, "/", "");`

Please help me fix it

Comment: Are you saying that you are seeing `slng=zh;` and `slng=vi` but you only want to see `slng=vi`?

Comment: You should post a little more code, what's around `setcookie`? from where does the "zh" comes from?